# Adding event listener onMount

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add an Event Listener to an dDOM Element on mount like:

```
        var isScrolling = null;
        console.log(document.getElementById("the-container"));
        document.getElementById("the-container").addEventListener('wheel', e => {
            window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);

            // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
            isScrolling = setTimeout(() => {
                // Run the callback
                scale.value = (Math.round(parseFloat(Math.min(Math.max(minScale, (scale.value + (e.wheelDelta / elWidth))), maxScale)) * 1e2) / 1e2);
                rerender();
            }, 150);
        }, false);
```

When adding in on the body element it's working as expected. When using the container element it's not. The element exists and there is no error message. When adding it manually in the console it also works. Using Vue3 composition api.

Comment: Define "working as expected".

Comment: See https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEKgqRB

Comment: @tony19  working as expected means that the event fires. The event listener is added to the element but it's not firing.

Comment: Well it works as expected in the codepen I've linked above. Can you share a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 I got it working using your codepen. I wrapped it all into another element then it worked. Thanks.